# Why did Luke leave his lightsaber?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens

In *Star Wars: The Force Awakens*, We see Luke's lightsaber is not with him. What is the reason for that? Is it because he lost it? If so; when, where and while doing what?

I'm asking because a lightsaber is really important for a Jedi, as Obi-Wan constantly reminded Anakin.

[image]